# Iterating over tuple of arrays

Tags: templates, d

I'm trying to iterate over a tuple of arrays of different types, calling a function with each element. My current implementation is like this:

```
// Some T... is defined up here.

// ArrayTuple!(T) is a TypeTuple of arrays of each type in T.
ArrayTuple!(T) data;
void iterate(alias func, uint n = 0)()
{
    static if(n < T.length)
    {
        foreach(elem; data[n])
            func(elem);

        iterate!(func, n + 1)();
    }
}
```

And is used as such:

```
void foo(T)(T elem)
{
    ...
}

iterate!(foo)();
```

Works great for the most part, but a delegate template can't be passed for `func`. Any suggestions on an implementation which supports template functions with stack pointers?

Comment: not a D programmer, not sure, maybe [this](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_range.html#zip) will help

Answer (score 1):

What would be the type of the delegate's parameter? You can't take the address of a method template and get a delegate - you'd need to instantiate it with a type.

Comment: The whole point is that it's typed a number of different ways, depending on the types in T. That's why it's being passed as a template alias parameter instead of a function pointer or delegate.

Comment: Are you asking how to make this work with a templated method, then?

Comment: Judging by "functions with stack pointers", I'd guess "no". I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve - nested functions can't be templated, and you need to pass a template by alias to allow `iterate` to instantiate it with arbitrary types.

Comment: Why can't nested functions be templated? I'm using template nested functions just fine..

Comment: Anyway, the answer is that `iterate` needs to receive both the template to instantiate, and a context for the delegate. D doesn't provide a type for a delegate stack context by itself, so you can't really construct a delegate or pass a pointer to a context for a static function.